# Translating Fortran Code to a Formula

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, fortran

I want to test some parts of my fortran code. I know 
that there is a command "FortranForm" for mathematica
that does the reverse. If there is something else online 
that would be great also.

Is there something like this for easy cases of Fortran Code?
For example what i want to convert right now is:
 result= exp((-0.5)*((delta_w/delta)*(delta_w/delta)))

Comment: Not a Fortran user so this may be nonsense, but might the */ part a typo?

Comment: thanks there was something multiplied, which i edited out. +1

Comment: Someone wrote f2mma, a program that does this, and there are several published references to it, but I've been unable to find the code itself :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before with Mathematica v6 to help me understand a Fortran IV function, and the only way I found was by systematically replacing the Fortran constructs with Mathematica ones by hand.  While not necessary in your case, Mathematica has both [`Goto`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Goto.html) and [`Label`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Label.html). For the longer functions, this requires some discipline, but is doable.  In your case, the translation is quite easy; it is simply

```
Exp[ -0.5*(deltaw/delta)^2]
```

BTW, in your code `(delta_w/delta)*(delta_w/delta)` can be simplified to `(delta_w/delta)**2`.

Alternatively, if you are just interested in testing the code itself and you have v8, compile the function into a dynamic library, and use the new [Wolfram LibraryLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LibraryLink.html) feature to access it from inside of Mathematica.  This functionality presupposes that your using C, and while I know it is possible to combine programs that use both languages, I have not done it.  So, this option is not for the faint of heart, but it could give interesting results.

Comment: For the curious, the function I translated was used to calculate the spherical harmonic contribution at a point up to a specified l. The function was a nightmare involving an outer loop, plus at least two partially overlapping inner loops, and it was done entirely by using `if` and `goto`.  It required a genius to put together, and it was a nightmare to figure out how it worked.

Comment: @tarrasch, if you ever decide to try using `LibraryLink` with Fortran, I'd be very interested in hearing about the results.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a *good* solution, but often the easiest way is to interpret the formula as `TraditionalForm`, possibly editing it first to fix problems such as underscores being interpreted as patterns.  You can automate some of this editing using `StringReplace`.

This solution might be faster and easier for small formulas than implementing something more complicated.  After all the main issue (and sometimes the only one) is to somehow interpret `f(x)` as a function rather than multiplication.

Make a `TradinionalForm` cell (new cell, ctrl-shift-t), paste your formula, then evaluate it.

Answer (score 2):

A method that sometimes works, though alas not in this example, is as follows.

(1) Mouse over the '+' at the top left of the next cell location. A pop-up will say "Choose how to enter input". Left-click mouse.

(2) On drop-down menu select "Free-form input".

(3) You should now see an '=' sign inside an orange box to the left of the cell. Enter your input and evaluate it. You might want to wrap it in Unevaluated[] so as not to perform actual computations.

A pane will appear below the input, with the result.

[image]

Not so useful in this instance, but sometimes one gets closer to the mark.

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: That might just be because of the name `delta` which is confusing for the translator. Perhaps changing `delta` to something else say `qxj` and importing might work.